# Progmatically using npm from nodejs build script

Tags: node.js, npm, jake

I have a large project which contains multiple node application endpoints, each with their own package.json file.

I have a main build script (written in jake) which sets up a given environment, runs tests, packages apps etc.

So is there a way for the root build script to run "npm install" on the given directories.

I expect psudo code would be:

```
var npm = require("npm");
var package1Directory = "some-directory";
npm.install(packageDirectory);
```

Cannot find any documentation around this though so not sure if it is possible... so is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at [the docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Using-npm-Programmatically):

```
var npm = require("npm")
npm.load(myConfigObject, function (er) {
  if (er) return handlError(er)
  npm.commands.install(["some", "args"], function (er, data) {
    if (er) return commandFailed(er)
    // command succeeded, and data might have some info
  })
  npm.on("log", function (message) { .... })
})
```

Also have a look at [this example](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/bin/npm-cli.js), which gives some more insights on how to use `npm` programmatically.

Comment: I tried navigating the npm site but all documentation seemed to lead back to the nodejs site, thanks for the link. This isn't that clear on how to call install on a child directory rather than the root directory but can go look in the source code to find out more.